# Circle more round

Tags: edges

We can see there a sharp edges (its not ideal circle).
How to make this custom circle more round?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Select the circle (or Mesh) which you want to make round.
2. Go to modifiers tab, Apply **Subdivision modifier** to the mesh.

(You can increase subdivision counts according your needs. Increasing Count To higher value than 2, Cause blender respond slower)(Recommended=2)

You will get the more round circle but it will increase vertices count..

[image]